# Jenkins has no list of available plugins / can't update

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I just installed Jenkins 1.575 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  When I go to the plugins section to add plugins, nothing shows up.  If I go to Advanced and click check now, it just hangs at Updating....

- I am running nginx to do a proxy pass for port 80 to port 8080 where
  jenkins is running.  I don't know much on configuring nginx.  When I
  first started Jenkins, I had the reverse proxy error but dismissed it. Not sure if that is related.
- I also had ufw running but disabling that did not help
- I also don't see any errors in the Jenkins log

My nginx.conf related to Jenkins:

```
http {
        server {
           listen 80 default;
            server_name _;
            location /{
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 $scheme://localhost;
                }
        }
 .....
```

Any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (at least temporary) in @rcomblen answer to: [Unable to find plugins in list of available plugins in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215985/6771046). It has you manually download the plugin list and post it to Jenkins.

I think the problem may have to do with my VPN. The VPN isn't setup that well and doesn't let you connect to the internet through the VPN. So when I click the button to update the plugin list, I think it tries to download from my browser instead of on the server and Jenkins isn't able to download the plugin list.

Answer (score 0):

I think your nginx setting is good, maybe you can try to restart your jenkins.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

And this is my jenkins site conf of Nginx.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jenkins
server {
  listen   *:80;

  [...]

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things and hours of searching... i've ended up with the upgrade of jenkins to version 1.638. This helps to solve the frustrated problem with empty available plugins in older version of jenkins!